# How to disable the option "open" in Internet Explorer when I click a link containing ms office document?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, ms-office

I have a problem. My site is containing ms office documents (doc,xls). When users click on a link in Internet Explorer they get the choice to either "open", "save" or "save as". How do I disable the option "Open"? I do not want the user to open the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `X-Download-Options` HTTP response header was introduced in IE8 to control visibility of the "Open" button on the file download dialog. I wrote about this header here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx

This header partially obsoletes existing "DownloadOptions" META tag which was introduced in IE6 on XPSP2: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533689(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you. I added <meta name="DownloadOptions" content="noopen|nosave" /> in page. I did not get to use "X-Download-Options" in .htaccess.